# Making Buttons Instantiated at run-time via script have onClick functions declared correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, parent-child, instantiation

In my program I am instantiating buttons at run-time. These buttons are being instantiated to a canvas. They *should* reference a main object, a car. The buttons should refer to all the parts of the car. When I click a button, I want the camera to zoom in on the correct car part. The buttons have the same text as the car parts. Since they are being instantiated from a button prefab in assets at run-time, I don’t know how to code it where if I click on it, it zooms in on the correct part.

My first attempt was to attach a script to the button prefab that when clicked it would read its own text (because it grabs the text from all the children in another script) then it would read all the children text, and compare and find where the button text was the same as the children part text, then it would grab that child GameObject and it would reference that GameObject’s transform and transform the camera to the location.

I can transform the camera and everything because I have already done this by using raycast to click the car part, but I just don’t know how to assign onClick to the buttons. The code needs to be reusable so I was trying to design it where it could be used for any object ...

---

[Picture of the inspector car and parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BzkX.png)
[Picture of inspector and script that is instantiating the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UspFo.png)

Below is my attempt to solve this problem. This script is attached to the button prefab...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ifClickedZoomy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objofparts;
    public GameObject cm;

    Button btn;
    string nameofobj;

    void start()
    {


        btn = this.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(going);
        btn.name = nameofobj;

        var temp = objofparts.gameObject.transform.Find(nameofobj);

        //btn.onClick.AddListener(delegate { Zoomy(temp); });
    }

    public void Zoomy(Transform target)
    {

        cm.transform.position = target.transform.position + Vector3.one * 0.5f;
        cm.transform.LookAt(target);
    }

    void going()
    {
        /*
        if(btn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text == "SkyCar")
        {
            GameObject target = GameObject.Find("SkyCar");
            Vector2 targpos = target.transform.position;

            cm.transform.position = targpos;
        }
        */
    }

}
```

Comment: Still .. I wouldn't go this way. Rather as discussed in previous questions of yours fill in the data from the script that instantiates the buttons. Your main issue here might be that `Start` needs a capital `S` otherwise it is never called ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button prefab could have a script already attached to the button object. In this script you would have a public method called `ClickBehaviour()` that is pre linked to The OnClick.

This script should have a `delegate` method that can be set externally from a method called `SetClickBehaviour`.

A delegate is basically a variable that stores a function with a particular signature. So a delegate void is storing a void function. You can set a delegate to be a particular function. When you call the delegate as if it was a real function, it actually calls the function it is storing. In this way you can swap which function actually gets called at runtime by changing which function is stored in the delegate.

So, you would instantiate the button prefab, then send it the behaviour to link with it by calling `newButton.SetClickBehaviour(methodToCall);`

So SetClickBehaviour is responsible for changing what is stored in the delegate..

Then inside ClickBehaviour, you would call the delegate method that was set externally.

So ClickBehaviour actually calls that delegate.

Button Spawner

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Button Prefab
    [SerializeField] 
    RuntimeButton RuntimeButtonPrefab = default;

    // Where to create instantiated buttons
    [SerializeField] 
    Canvas ParentCanvas = default;

    void Start()
    {
        //Create Buttons
        RuntimeButton newRuntimeButton1 = Instantiate(RuntimeButtonPrefab, ParentCanvas.transform);
        newRuntimeButton1.SetClickBehaviour(MethodThatButton1ShouldDo);

        RuntimeButton newRuntimeButton2 = Instantiate(RuntimeButtonPrefab, ParentCanvas.transform);
        newRuntimeButton2.SetClickBehaviour(MethodThatButton2ShouldDo);
    }

    //These methods could be anything and from any other scripts
    public void MethodThatButton1ShouldDo()
    {
        Debug.Log("Method for Button1 Worked!");
    }

    public void MethodThatButton2ShouldDo()
    {
        Debug.Log("Method for Button2 Worked!");;
    }


}
```

Button Script

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

//This class is attached to button
public class RuntimeButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    //An action is just a kind of delegate.
    Action clickBehaviour;

    //This is called from another script to define what method gets called when button is clicked.
    public void SetClickBehaviour(Action someMethodFromSomewhereElse)
    {
        clickBehaviour = someMethodFromSomewhereElse;
    }

    // This is linked in button inspector to the OnClick event.
    public void ClickBehaviour()
    {
        clickBehaviour.Invoke();
    }

}
```

In Action:
[image]

One thing to note as well: in your updated question, your script is in charge of several things: making the button listen, finding a part, listening for clicks, moving the cameras, and "going". That's way too much for one script to handle! It's a good idea to parse these ideas out into different scripts, each with only one main responsibility. I find this often helps diagnose problems, and can suggest possible solutions. In my example scripts, RuntimeButton is only responsible for capturing an OnClick, and calling its delegate. It doesn't care what that delegate does.

ButtonSpawner is only in charge of spawning buttons. In a real program, the two methods that get passed to the buttons would definitely reside in separate scripts, since they have nothing to do with spawning buttons. I just put them in there for this minimal example.

Comment: I have seen the delegate behavior in passing a GameObject to a Transform, but I'm not really sure how it works. Could you explain a little bit about what a delegate is and how it applies to this specific concept?

Comment: Added some more delegate info. Hope that helps

Comment: Could I show you the code that I wrote to try and do what I was doing before? I thought I was doing the delegate stuff and then my buttons weren't actually working. I didn't know if it was a Unity inspector (tying things together) issue or if it was my code... I have fixed some parenting issues that may have caused it and I am putting the script on the parent object that contains all of this stuff.

Comment: Yes add any relevant code to your question and explain your prefab, and car parts organization

Comment: I have updated my original question with my code sample and pictures of 1. the inspector with the car and children parts, and also the game object that holds the script that instantiates all the buttons (and also changes the names of the buttons to make the parts of the car)

Comment: So now since it is spawning buttons, how can I go about tying it into my car part prefab? I could use the somemethodfromsomewhereelse... and I could put a script on the car, or back onto the button to say if it is clicked and the name matches the car part, zoom in on that game object?

Comment: I hinted at the answer in my note above, you need a separate "thing": The need to  zoom in on a car part. So that sounds like yet another script called CarPartZoomIn. That script might have a reference to a car part, a camera, and a method to zoom into it. So when you spawn your buttons, you would pass the method in the CarPartZoomIn Script. The button shouldn't care what happens after it's pressed, only that the appropriate message was sent!

Comment: Look up "Tell, don't ask". The idea of a button checking if it's associated with the right car part doesn't make sense. Whatever made the button should be concerned about that. Whether it be the Unity Editor, or a runtime script. The button itself should only deal with clicks, and that's it.

Comment: Actually this is not needed .. simply add the callback to `btn.onClick.AddListener(() => { /* whatever */});` is what you need.

Comment: I'm still struggling to wrap my head around this.
The button script only returns that it was clicked, then the runtime button script deals with instantiating the button, and instantiates two buttons...
Then I need a main script to read the children and say for as many children as there are, there are that many buttons...
I also need to have the buttons actually know what the child parts are and zoom in on those parts.
I can do that zoom stuff, my big issue is how to traverse the children dynamically with code.

Comment: Ok so you have a button spawner that creates, and sets up the buttons. Its job is done. The buttons, when created, now know what to do when clicked (call the delegate that the spawner sent them). Now the button's job is done. The issue you're having is where the delegated method is coming from.  This method should probably be a ZoomIn method, in some other script. This other script should only be responsible for zooming into a car part that it's linked to. So it would have a private CarPart field, a private Camera field, and a public method called ZoomIn() that zooms the camera to the CarPart.

Comment: @derHugo Yes, that works fine too. But I find callbacks to be more difficult to figure out in the future when I revisit code compared to delegates. Just a personal style :)

Comment: @AdamB well Inspector references (such as your persistent callback for the button to invoke the action) are way easier to lose than a coded `AddListener` especially version control wise ;)